# Max count SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, max

I will explain my question with a practical example so that it is easier to visualize the issue. I have build this query:

```
Select 
    E.Tipo_Esp, F.Nome, F.Apelido, 
    count (Ac.id_acto) as total_consultas 
from 
    Especialidade as E 
right join 
    Funcionario as F on F.id_Esp = E.id_Esp
inner join 
    Acto as Ac on Ac.id_func = F.id_func
inner join 
    TipoActo as TA on TA.id_Tipo_acto = Ac.id_Tipo_acto
where 
    TA.Descricao_Acto = 'Consulta'
group by 
    E.Tipo_Esp, F.Nome, F.Apelido
order by
    count(Ac.id_acto) DESC
```

to arrive to the following result:

```
Tipo_Esp  Nome  Apelido  total_consultas
Ortopedia Maria  Antonia  3
Ortopedia Luis   Cruz     1
Cirurgia  André  Martins  2
Cirurgia  Diogo  Martins  1
```

However what I need to arrive is this:

```
Tipo_Esp  Nome  Apelido  total_consultas
Ortopedia Maria  Antonia  3
Cirurgia  André  Martins  2
```

meaning I only need the higher count for each "Tipo_Esp". I have tried to apply the max count function with the above query as a subquery but it did went well as expected. can someone help me with this issue please? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
with orig as (
  Select E.Tipo_Esp, F.Nome, F.Apelido, count (Ac.id_acto) as total_consultas from 
  Especialidade as E 
  right join Funcionario as F on F.id_Esp = E.id_Esp
  inner join Acto as Ac on Ac.id_func = F.id_func
  inner join TipoActo as TA on TA.id_Tipo_acto = Ac.id_Tipo_acto
  WHERE TA.Descricao_Acto = 'Consulta'
  GROUP BY E.Tipo_Esp, F.Nome, F.Apelido
  ORDER BY count(Ac.id_acto) DESC
)
select o.* 
from orig o
inner join (
  select tipo_esp, max(total_consultas) as maxtotal
  from orig
  group by tipo_esp
) t on o.tipo_esp = t.tipo_esp and o.total_consultas = t.maxtotal
```